# How to display info from a query string then remove the string in php

Tags: javascript, php

This is really hard to explain, I'm trying to remove a query string from my url after I've displayed the data from the string.

in file1.php I have a redirection to file2.php after some checks

```
header('Location: file2.php?var=somemessage');
```

in file2.php I echo $_GET['var']; to display the message then use javascript to remove the query string from url

```
if (location.href.match(/\?.*/) && document.referrer) {
   location.href = location.href.replace(/\?.*/, '');
}
```

The problem here is that I get a notice of undifined index: var in file2.php. How do I get around this to remove the query string and still display the message?

I don't want to pass the message from a session.

Comment: If you set `location.href`, you will also navigate to the new url you set (the one without `var`. Because of that, the PHP script will be executed again, but without the string, hence the error. Have a look at the history API, and especially [history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries). Another possibility is to set a cookie first, and read back the cookie after the redirect.

Comment: Wow! I didn't think about that. Thanks :)

Comment: You can find more informations reading this question [javascript - Modify the URL without reloading the page - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page#3354511) .